# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Entity Framework Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

> Error: The instance of entity type 'Review' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being
>   tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
>   instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.

When I am trying to update records then I found the issue. Anyone can solve the issue?

Controller Code:

```
var review = ReviewDTO.ConvertToViewModel(await this._reviewRepository.GetByIdAsync(id));       

        if(review == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        review.Id = id;
        review.Approve = true;
        await this._reviewRepository.UpdateAsync(ReviewDTO.ConvertToEntity(review));
```

and Repository Code:

```
try
{ 
    this._context.Update(review);
    await this._context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

ReviewDTO class method ConvertToViewModel. I am converting ViewModel class to Entity Class.

```
public static ReviewViewModel ConvertToViewModel(LTSystem.Entity.Review dataEntity)
    {
        if (dataEntity == null)
            return null;

        return new ReviewViewModel
        {
            Id = dataEntity.Id,
            ItemId = dataEntity.ItemId,
            Comment = dataEntity.Comment,
            DateCreated = dataEntity.DateCreated,
            DateUpdated = dataEntity.DateUpdated,
            Rating = dataEntity.Rating,
            Approve = dataEntity.Approve,
            UserId = dataEntity.UserId
        };
    }
```

Comment: You have two fields that are labeled 'Id'. Adjust the name. More Information would be helpful here as well for better visibility on this complete issue.

Comment: @AllanF.Gagnon could you please give me some example?

Comment: Could you add some of the relevant code? It's hard to say what the issue is.

Comment: @juunas I have updated my post including example code.

Comment: change your top line to the following: var review = ReviewDTO.ConvertToViewModel(await this._reviewRepository.AsNoTracking().GetByIdAsync(id));

Comment: @AllanF.Gagnon no way to change in controller but I changed in repository. Seems no error but data is not updating in database. There is no effect.

Comment: You have duplicate 'id' fields that is causing this issue. you could add .FirstOrDefault(); on the end and verify that the review id is returned when debugging.

Comment: @AllanF.Gagnon did no luck.

Comment: @NoorAllSafaet - Is the object null?

Comment: @AllanF.Gagnon value no change made in db.

Comment: Share all the relevant code(includes custom classes like ReviewDTO and methods like ConvertToViewModel()) if you need a community code review or debug support.

Comment: @XueliChen I have added the method in main body of post. Please take a look.